# Where should I add connection for garage subpanel with two 200amp service panels?

Tags: electrical

Here my meter[image]

Which feeds into this panel inside
[image]

Then into these two
[image]
[image]

Meter also feeds into this panel outside
[image]
Which appears to feed into this panel inside
[image]

Somewhere in that mix there's also connections for 2 central air units that have their own breaker boxes at the units.
Assuming all that info is correct Where would be the best spot to connect for a garage sub-panel. Wont have much load on it a few outlets, led lighting, and a 220v 8amp ac unit

Edit:1
After crawling back under the house with a better flashlight it appears this panel powers all the inside breaker boxes.

[image]
[image]

And the outside panel only powers the a/c subpanels this was confirmed by turning them off (don't know why i didn't do that in first place) Also checked the fuses in the panel are actually 100amp. I'm a bit concerned that even though it's never blown a main fuse it may be more than the designed load on it. Also still waiting for the engineer to call back from the utility company to verify my capacity but I may be pushing that as well. I have noticed when the a/c kicks on all the lights in the house dim. So as of now looks like I'll be using the outside panel which is what I was leaning toward in the first place.

Edit 2
Meter face
[image]
Ac unit 1
[image]
Ac unit 2
[image]
Single oven
[image]
Double oven
[image]
Breaker labels
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit 3

So the plot thickens. Apparently someone upgraded to 320a service and never informed The utility company (field technician) came about 6 months ago and swapped existing meter base for a 320a smart meter base apparently never checked with our communicated that to engineering. The field engineer was here today the service line is an undersized 3 phase line with only 2 wires going into the meter. They're coming out next week to install a proper service line

[image]

Edit 4
Grille
[image]
Cooktop
[image]
Outside load panel label
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136620/discussion-on-question-by-richard-soucie-where-should-i-add-connection-for-garag).

Comment: What's the nameplate amp rating of your air compressor? Also, can you post photos of the labeling on the inside of your outdoor panel's door please?

Comment: Meter is a CL200 - which in "meters and panels are different" actually means it's good for 250A, AIUI (200A continuous. My CL320 meter feeds 400A service.)

Comment: One last question: what's the amp rating of the main breaker in the outside panel?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel pics added air compressor is 16amp 120v. The outside panel doesn't have a main breaker just the 2 100amp breakers that feed the ac subpanels. Thought the engineer said the meter was 320a but I may have misunderstood. I'll make sure they change that out as well

Comment: @RichardSoucie sorry for the extra question, but do the air conditioners have heat kits fitted?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yes they do the one has it checked off the other one in not sure which kit is installed

Comment: @RichardSoucie the label that is checkmarked has the "NONE" box checked...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The other one is scratched off. I'm not sure if that's just dirt on the label or an actual check but they both provide heat

Comment: @RichardSoucie ah.  can you open up the units and post photos of the nameplates on their heater subassemblies please?

Comment: Would rather not the one unit that's clearly marked has the second most powerful marked so I'm just gonna assume they put the second most powerful in the other unit as well @ThreePhaseEel

Comment: @RichardSoucie -- sorry to bug you with another question, but what size are the wires running from the big switch on the inside to the two small panels adjacent to it?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many versions of what you have. Modify this. Add another circuit. Add another panel. Add another circuit. Make this change. Add another panel....

After a while, the system as a whole becomes a convoluted bowl of spaghetti unable to deliver proper power everywhere, having problems now, awaiting more problems in the near future and wasting electricity. You electrical distribution area should be a straight forward electrical tree running cool, clean, and ready for expansion.

My Recommendation: Remove the ancient main and replace it with the tallest new panel box you can buy. Then neatly organize all of the circuits into it without using any half-size breakers.

In Summary: Your electrical distribution system has been updated to many times already. The sooner you replace that mess the happier you will be.

Comment: That is a work in progress as wiring gets updated it will be switched to a new main panel dryer is coming out so that'll open two slots in the current panel.. Currently everything is so old that nothing has ground wires so that will be updated one room ata time. Going to add the subpanel for the garage to the outside panel which has its own mains and only 2 100 amp breakers in it. The electric co is coming next week to install a new service line and 320a meter